# The same PowerShell script in two tabs and his location

Tags: powershell

I have got one PowerShell script which is located in two directories wth diferent configuration.
I open both scripts in ISE editor as two tabs.
Am I able to determinated where is specific script located?
I have tried these commands.

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath('.\');
```

or

```
Get-Location;
```

But everytime I get path to first open script.

IE:

I have got script i location C:\A\script.ps1 and location C:\B\script.ps1.
I open script from first location and script from second location.
When I run command above I get path from first script.

Version of PowerShell is.

```
$host.Version ;
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      18362  1593
```

Comment: When you run the script you can use the automatic variable `$ScriptRoot`.

Comment: I have not got any response from $ScriptRoot;

Comment: It only works when you run the script - not when you open the script in ISE and run the single line of code there with F8 for example.

Comment: I am sorry. It is not possible. On my PC I can run script from ISE only with F8.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're pretty much out of luck. You would need to change the current directory if you depend on it with either `Set-Location` or `Push-Location`.

Comment: The correct automatic variable is `$PSScriptRoot` (it only works when you execute the script as-is, won't work if you execute the selection in ISE)

Comment: Ooops ... @MathiasR.Jessen .. .of course you're right `$PSScriptRoot` ... silly me.  ;-)

Comment: @DavidNovy if `F8` in ISE is _the only_ way you ever execute your code, use `$psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath` (eg. `Set-Location (Split-Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath -Parent)`)

Comment: Perfect. It Works.
Set-Location (Split-Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath -Parent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set-Location (Split-Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath -Parent);